# Is there any logic to the use of underscores in the middle of php function names?

Tags: php

Developers prefer function names that they can guess easily. The more intuitive the function name the better. Of course there is always auto-complete in a good IDE and as a last resort the manual.

The php function that is padding a string has the logical name `str_pad`. Guided by this you would predict that the name of the function that lowers the case of a string would be called `str_to_lower` or `str_tolower`. But in fact it is called `strtolower`. I can give numerous examples of this - in my view - inconsistent naming. Or is there a system?

Comment: Well..Have you gone through any kind of php tutorial where they say there is a naming system?

Comment: PHP's naming convention was established after long bouts of consuming high-proof alcoholic beverages: Anything goes, consistency is irrelevant, and another thing... *snooorrrrrre*

Comment: Is there any programming language where there is established a universal rule of how to name variables? If so I have been ignorant of it for the last 20 years. Instead, in my experience most projects have "style guides" that may have a word or two about how to name variables. But it varies widely.

Comment: Relevant discussion on php mailing list: https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=52424

Answer (score 1):

There are many different styles of variable naming. Generally you should keep to the prevailing style for the language. PHP, albeit historically a spaghetti mess of badly named variables and methods, has generally opted for camelCase naming, whereas a language like Ruby, tends to favour snake_case naming.

Comment: I can't find any guidance of the sort, about  recommendations for camelCase, snake case or StudleyCaps.  Either in Pear coding standards( 2007) https://pear.php.net/manual/en/standards.funcdef.php or the newer PSR 2 http://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-2/ , and I can't think of one Php function in the standard library that uses camelCase.